# How to configure my own application to use Tor?

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to write a little application which connects to the internet over Tor. The application uses the [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org) messaging library to get some information from another server and it's basically only one file that runs.

On the [TorifyHOWTO page](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO) I read some more information about torifying an application, but I'm kind of lost in that page. Also, I wonder if I should make some kind of wrapper around my program, or around the zeromq messaging library. I suppose I might be able to get zeromq to use a certain (Tor)proxy. But if so, what kind of proxy information should I use?

Could anybody provide some hints about where I could start? (example code would be great)

Comment: Probably, configure it to use Socks5 9050, the best way.

Answer (score 2):

You might just want to include socks proxy support, since Tor is a socks proxy. For that read about the [protocol on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Protocol). If you already have http proxy support you could ship a translating proxy, such as polipo, to communicate with Tor.

If your use-case requires control over Tor, [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) could be what you are looking for. Documentation and tutorials are available.

If your use-case requires to not rely on already deployed Tor, [Onionroute](http://www.onionroute.org/), a libary that is loaded into a process, could be an option. Please note, this isn't a project by the Tor Project and that it is to be considered experimental.

Answer (score 1):

To torify an application, you can use advtor:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/

Comment: Welcome to Tor.SE! You might want to expand this answer. Perhaps you could add an explanation of what advtor is, and add specific details of how it can be used to Torify an application - does it require specific configuration changes for example.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use Windows, plus I would like to be able to build it myself. It's not only the aim of achieving the connection, but also the aim of learning something new.. :) @SamuelWalker - Would you be able to give me some advice on where to get started?

Comment: Oh, Advanced Onion Router; a controversial Tor 'fork'.

Comment: @hubbtwea Unfortunately I have no experience with trying to torify applications.